# Is there a way to implement pointerlock in a scene exported from blender?

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf, pointerlock

On ThreeJS website, in the example *misc_controls_pointerlock*, the scene is built with geometries written directly in the code.
Is there a good way to implement this pointerlock in a model of a room that I would have conceived in Blender, for exemple exported in gltf?

I am an architect with good skills in Blender but a bit less in ThreeJS. I want to export scenes in Blender of architecture spaces, to let people navigate in them through the browser.